# $PGL_2$ image of special subgroups in $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p>2$ be a prime integer and let $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ be the corresponding finite field. Consider a subgroup $H$ of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$ which satisfies the following conditions:

1. The matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0& 1\\ -1 &0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)\in H$.
2. At least half of all elements in $H$ have trace $0$.

(Edited: I just realize that in fact I have even more conditions on $H$:

3. $H$ is not Abelian.
4. The trace of every element in $H$ is in fact in $\mathbb{F}_p$.)

My question is: Can we classify the isomorphism types of the image of $H$ in $PGL_2(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$?

I have done some MAGMA calculation for $p=3,5,7$. It seems that the quotient images of $H$ satisfying conditions (1)-(4) are either

1. A cyclic group.
2. Dihidral group.
3. Semiproduct of a cyclic group and a dihidral group. 
   I am wondering if this is always true.

(PS: I asked the same question at [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3449887/special-type-of-subgroups-of-sl-2-mathbbf-p2) since I am not sure if this question is trivial. According to comments, I will delete the one in math exchange.)

Comment: Indeed, simultaneous crossposting is discouraged, it would be better to delete one of the two posts.

Comment: Your condition (2) on the traces is very restrictive: any matrix in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$ with trace $0$ has characteristic polynomial $x^2 + 1$ (since the determinant is $1$), and since the field is $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ this polynomial has roots in the field. Therefore all such matrices are diagonalizable and conjugate in the special linear group to the matrix in (1). Maybe now consider the action of $H$ by conjugacy on these matrices: it looks like $H$ should be close to a Frobenius group. Sorry, I don't have time to make this more precise.

Comment: Continuing Mark Wildon's remarks, and since replacing $H$ by a conjugate makes no difference, your conditions are equivalent to requiring that at least half of the elements of $H$ have order $4$.

Comment: I'll reproduce here the comment I made on the other post: can't you deduce it from the classification of subgroups of $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$? (found in many places, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.1999)

Comment: Technicality: by assuming $H$ is not abelian, you seem to remove the possibility of a cyclic group, right?

Comment: @MarkWildon Thanks for your suggestion. I've spent some time to try to consider the conjugacy action of $H$ on the order $4$ elements (i.e. the trace $0$ elements). While I cannot see this action implies that my $H$ is a Frobenius group or something close. Maybe I am missing some important information? Thanks again for your hint.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, it's a nice observation. Could you say more about how to continue with this? Thanks.

Comment: @user44191 Yes. Actually, I want diheral type is the only possibility. While even if I added these conditions into my setups, I still get cyclic quotients.

Comment: Thanks for your reference @Aurel. While after a quick reading, I didn't find a way to prove what I want. Maybe I am slow, could you give more hints on it?

Comment: @Leo D I thought a bit more about the problem and it now seems harder to me. The most obvious examples of groups with your condition all seem to have a normal $2$-complement. Do you know of a group satisfying your condition which doesn't?

Comment: @MarkWildon's comment above tell us that half of the elements in the image of $H$ must be involutions. Looking at the subgroups of $PSL_2(p)$, one sees that a group satisfying this property is a subgroup of $D_{p+1}$, $D_{p-1}$ or $[p^2]\rtimes C_2$. Subgroups of the first two are either cyclic or dihedral, as you requested, and the latter is similar. I guess the latter is the group you've identified as the semidirect product of a cyclic group and a dihedral group, although I'm not sure I'd think of it that way myself. Anyway, the list is complete.

Comment: @Nick Gill: Hi Nick! I suggest you turn your comment into an answer. Are you using the classification suggested by Aurel, or something weaker?

Comment: Hey @MarkWildon. Yes, I just used the classification of subgroups of $PSL_2(p)$, although I think this is overkill. If I get a moment I'll write it up as an answer. I believe that this property of having half the elements as involutions is perhaps enough -- a result of CTC Wall classifies such groups -- when combined with a bit of information about Jordan rational form. There may be some gaps in that argument, I'll have to check!

Comment: @NickGill Many thanks for your comments. I am looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}$Let $H<\SL_2(p^2)$ for $p$ an odd prime. Let $Z=Z(\SL_2(p^2))$. The only important supposition is that half of all elements of $H$ have trace $0$. Let $h\in H$ be such an element.

As Mark Wildon [observes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346848/pgl-2-image-of-special-subgroups-in-sl-2-mathbbf-p2#comment868342_346848), the fact that $h$ has trace $0$, and is in $\SL_2(p^2)$, means that it has characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2+1$. This means that $h$ is diagonalizable in $\SL_2(p^2)$, and that $h^2=-I$. In particular $hZ$ is an involution in $\PSL_2(p^2)$ -- note that $\PSL_2(p^2)$ has a unique conjugacy class of these. Thus at least half of the elements in the group $HZ/Z<\PSL_2(p^2)$ are involutions.

Now we make use of the classification of subgroups of $\PSL_2(p^2)$ which is usually attributed to Dickson:

*Dickson, Leonard Eugene*, Linear groups. With an exposition of the Galois field theory. With an introduction by Wilhelm Magnus. Unabridged and unaltered republ. of the first ed, New York: Dover Publications, Inc. XVI, 312 p. (1958). [ZBL0082.24901](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0082.24901).

(Note that Bray-Holt-Roney Dougal also cite E.H. Moore and Wiman for early work on this result. Lots more information can be found in Michael Guidici's [preprint on the subject, "Maximal subgroups of almost simple groups with socle $\PSL(2, q)$"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703685).)

Anyway, one can go through the list given by Dickson and see directly that one of the following holds:

- $HZ/Z$ is cyclic of order $2$;
- $HZ/Z$ is dihedral of order $r$ where $r$ divides $2p$, $p^2-1$ or $p^2+1$;
- $HZ/Z$ is isomorphic to $E\rtimes C_2$ where $E$ denotes an elementary abelian group of order $p^2$ ($E$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $\PSL_2(p^2)$), and the non-identity element in the $C_2$ acts on $E$ by inversion.

Note that I consider the Klein 4-group to be a dihedral group of order $4$ in the list above.

**Final remark**: Using Dickson's result is probably overkill. As I mentioned [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346848/pgl-2-image-of-special-subgroups-in-sl-2-mathbbf-p2#comment869388_346848), C. T. C.  Wall has classified all groups where at least half of the elements are involutions ([Wall - On groups consisting mostly of involutions](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/on-groups-consisting-mostly-of-involutions/554A7AE2A5C7B537B76CB098A8C6E2E2) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=249503))). It seems likely that this result could be used instead. (And there are probably even more elementary methods.)

Comment: Ah, this is a really nice answer with sufficient reference! Thanks very much for your help.